# PHP/MYSQL returning incorrect results - MYSQL WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, apache, select, where-clause

Heres the situation, a variable, $username is set to "scott" or something. then these lines happen:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'") or     die(mysql_error());
print_r(mysql_fetch_array($query));
```

This prints our the following, which is what is in the table at the time.

```
 ( [0] => 1 [userid] => 1 [1] => 0 [username] => 0 [2] => 0 [password] => 0 [3] => 0 [email] => 0 [4] => 1346924695 [time] => 1346924695 )
```

How can i fix this? Thanks

Comment: Table structure please! Also try printing out separate elements and post the result. $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $row['username'];

Comment: Dont forget to escape that $username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the data type of all. Guess everything is in `int`.

You can do it in MySQL Console as:

```
desc `tablename`;
```

You might need to re-up all the rows!

Answer (score 0):

the query returns the table as an array and you are printing this array.The returned value is correct.
Try printing the array element.

```
$result_array = mysql_fetch_array($query)
print_r($result_array[0]["username"])
```

it will print the username on the 0th row of the table.
plz check the syntax